# How to perform multiple tricks whilst airborne

Tags: olliolli-2

I am able to perform tricks whilst preparing my ollie on the ground, but I don't seem to be able to perform any subsequent tricks whilst in the air.

What button combinations should I use to perform multiple tricks whilst in the air, or do you just complete one trick and then focus on getting your landing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having played this much more now it seems that you cannot perform any additional tricks whilst airborne.

You prepare your kick trick whilst travelling along the ground or a rail then execute it. Once it has been executed, the trick is complete and it's time to focus on your landing.

In order to keep performing tricks, you'll want to land in a manual. `L-Stick` (left or right) + `X` as close to the ground as you can manage.